# Is it possible to add a new property to an rsyslog message?

Tags: rsyslog, rainerscript

Messages in rsyslog come with a set of [properties](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/properties.html). A nice thing about some of these properties is that they don't reside in the message text, so you can treat them as metadata. Is there a way to add a new property to the message, without having to put it in the message text, such that it would be accessible to another rsyslog instance in RainerScript (i.e. referring to it as `$!mycustomproperty`?)

Comment: 2rs2ts: have found a solution to this?

Comment: @woodz no, unfortunately not. Most people in the industry have seemingly moved on to stuff like fluent-bit, and at my company where we still do rsyslog, whatever we can't put in JSON we just cope with not being immediately parsed as a property, by instead just re-parsing the custom property as if it is part of the `msg` field, with a regex. To be clear, this is just how we have worked around it, and it isn't a solution IMO, since it's requiring us to write redundant/verbose parsing code.

Answer (score 1):

you can add your own template like

```
$template $your_custom_conf_name $FILE_TO_MONITOR_ALIAS,\"<%pri%>%protocol-version% %timestamp:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% filename="source_name" %app-name% %procid% %msgid% %msg%\n\"
```

Actually, I needed the filename in each line so the above custom template works for me.

Comment: I was curious about a solution that did not involve adding the property to the message itself.

Comment: you are not going to touch the actual msg part, u r just defining your own template so anything that is other than the $msg property is going to be u r metadata is that right?

Comment: Defining the template just changes what gets written to a file or forwarded to another server. The other server would have to parse out certain fields to be able to define them as custom properties, but that would, in the end, leave that data in the `msg` property. This is my understanding.